# specifying a slot value as a key when removing duplicates

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp, clos

The following code does what I want:

```
 1 (defclass some-class ()
 2   ((some-slot
 3       :initarg :somearg
 4       :initform (error ":somearg not specified"))))
 5 (defparameter *alpha* (make-instance 'some-class :somearg 3))
 6 (defparameter *beta*  (make-instance 'some-class :somearg 5))
 7 (defparameter *gamma* (make-instance 'some-class :somearg 3))
 8 (princ (slot-value *beta* 'some-slot)) (terpri)
 9 (defparameter *delta* (list *alpha* *beta* *gamma*))
10 (princ *delta*) (terpri)
11 (princ (remove-duplicates *delta*
12          :test #'equal
13          :key (lambda (x) (slot-value x 'some-slot))))
14 (terpri)
5
(#<SOME-CLASS #x21C1D71E> #<SOME-CLASS #x21C1DAFE> #<SOME-CLASS #x21C1DC3E>)
(#<SOME-CLASS #x21C1DAFE> #<SOME-CLASS #x21C1DC3E>)
```

But is there a way to do this without having to write the function on line 13?  Is there a shorthand way to specify as the key a slot value in the class instance?

The following blows up with a syntax error, of course, but it gives the general idea of what I'm seeking.

```
 1 (princ (remove-duplicates *delta*
 2          :test #'equal
 3          :key '(slot-value 'some-slot)))
 4 (terpri)
*** - FUNCALL: (SLOT-VALUE 'SOME-SLOT) is not a function name; try using a
      symbol instead
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a `:reader` or `:accessor`.

Doing

```
(defclass some-class ()
  ((some-slot
    :initarg :somearg :reader some-slot
    :initform (error ":somearg not specified"))))
```

should let you re-write lines 11 through 13 as

```
(princ (remove-duplicates *delta* :test #'equal :key #'some-slot))
```

That is, `(some-slot x)` is equivalent to `(slot-value x 'some-slot)` if the slot in question has a reader/accessor.

---

After-Sleep Edit:

You also don't need to bother setting `:initform` to error; a slot will do that by default if you don't specify a default value and someone tries to read it. If you *don't* want the error, you do something  like `:initform nil`. Check out this excellent [CLOS tutorial](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/clos-tutorial/index.html) as well as [chapters 16 and 17 of Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) for more information about objects in Common Lisp.

Also, in the future if you have working code that you'd like style advice on, do check out [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There's a small, but active population of Lisp reviewers.

Comment: Inaimathi, the reason I set :initform to error is to trigger an error not when the slot is accessed, but earlier, when the object is created.  Does that do this for me?

Comment: @Bill - Ah, I see. No, the default behavior is to error when an unset slot is accessed. You got it then.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a reader function for the slot in the `defclass` and provide that as key function to `remove-duplicates`. For example, add this line to the slot definition:

```
:reader some-slot
```

and then use this in the call of `remove-duplicates`:

```
:key #'some-slot
```